# Do TFX pipelines support training on TPUs?

Tags: keras, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, tpu, tfx

I am new to TFX and I would like to know if it's possible to create a TFX pipeline that can train Keras models on TPUs nodes using TPUStrategy from a TPUClusterResolver. Looking at TFX documentation, it is not clear to me if such is possible.

Any feedback about this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Note: Im using TF v2

Comment: Hello, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TFX Pipeline supports TPU out-of-the-box for TPU-enabled Estimators, the same `model_config.model` can be used to configure an estimator regardless of whether it is trained on CPU or TPU.

To train in TPU, you should follow the following actions:

1. Configure a **`tpu_footprint`** in your deployment file and the desired
   trainer stanza of your service file.
2. Include an empty **`TPUSettings`**
   message in your custom_config file.
3. And as an optional action,
   configure a TPUEstimator-specific args in
   **`model_config.tpu_estimator`**.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I forgot to mention that Im using TF v2.